# Finding smallest value in array using functions?

Tags: c, arrays

Hello so currently I am trying to work on a project, but I have run into a roadblock and i've been staring at this code for hours and can't figure out what's going on.

My main issue is finding the smallest value of the array in which the user has entered... I was able to get the largest value and output that, but for some reason I can't get the smallest value to output the correct result. I keep getting 0.0....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5
double getValidRainfall() {
double result;

printf("\nEnter a rainfall amount: ");
scanf("%lf", &result);

while (result < 0.0) {
    printf("%.2lf is not a valid rainfall amount.", result);
    printf("\nEnter another rainfall amount: ");
    scanf("%lf", &result);
}
return result;
}
double calculateTotal(double rainfall[], int size) {
double result = 0.0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    result += rainfall[i];
}
return result;
}

double findLargest(double rainfall[], int size) {
double result = 0.0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (rainfall[i] > result)
        result = rainfall[i];
}
return result;
}

double findSmallest(double rainfall[], int size) {
double result = 0.0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (rainfall[i] < result) 
        result = rainfall[i];
}
return result;
}

main() {
double rainfall[SIZE], totalRainfall, averageRainfall;
double largestRainfall, smallestRainfall;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    rainfall[i] = getValidRainfall();

totalRainfall = calculateTotal( rainfall, SIZE );
averageRainfall = totalRainfall / SIZE;
largestRainfall = findLargest(rainfall, SIZE);
smallestRainfall = findSmallest(rainfall, SIZE);


// outputs
printf("\nThank you.\n");
printf("The total rainfall for these 5 days is: %.2lf\n", totalRainfall);
printf("The average rainfall is %.2lf\n", averageRainfall);
printf("The largest daily rainfall is %.1lf\n", largestRainfall);
printf("The smallest daily rainfall is %.1lf\n", smallestRainfall);

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: In `findSmallest()`, `double result = 0.0;` --> `double result = DBL_MAX;`

Comment: The longer your code the less likely are people to help you. As @VittorioRomeo said, you should try to post only the parts of the code that seem to be the problem. Id you are new to programming, and don't know how to find the part of the code that causes problems, try debugging line by line, and find the place where your expectations do not agree with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function below assign the `result` to the largest value possible or one from the array itself otherwise, it will give you the wrong result as `0.0` will always be lesser than anything in the array(considering the rainfall amount a +ve number) & the condition will always be false.

```
double findSmallest(double rainfall[], int size) {
    double result = DBL_MAX; // or double result = rainfall[0], if size >= 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (rainfall[i] < result) 
            result = rainfall[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wish you could hear how loud I slapped my own head, excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously all entries of rainfall are more that `0.0` you need to initialise `result` to a radically high value, not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your result variable to the first element in your array or something higher than all the values (the first method being more efficient). Since you are initializing it to 0.0 unless the values are negative it will stay 0.0. Therefore I would suggest this:

```
double result = rainfall[0];
```